# How to customize actionbar action item?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Expected:

[image]

But action item appears with capitalized text:

[image]

I tried to play with styles with no success. Here one version:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:capitalize">none</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Text</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/ActionMenu</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionMenu" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Text" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item"
        android:title="action item"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

Who really knows what attribute should be changed to get the desired result?

Comment: Android converts any text there into capital letters, it cannot be changed. But if want small letters there then manually create an image with text and same background color as ActionBar.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way, make a text layout for your menu title:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_item"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/action_title"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Layout `action_title`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

   <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/action_title" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"     

      android:text="action item"
      android:textSize="10sp"  
      android:textColor="@color/black"  
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now `action title` should show what you give

Comment: Can you confirm this works? This is so weird! I have been fighting all day trying to get actionLayout to work, but absolutely cannot on a Nexus5 running Lollipop. The menu item only just shows up as text and I absolutely cannot get it to honor the layout! I'll post a simplified version of my code within [hopefully] a few days.

Comment: yes my app use this way, work fine. Hope see your codes

Comment: I have uploaded a fresh project that repros my problem here: https://github.com/paulpv/ToolbarSwitch What on earth am I spacing on that is causing the Switch to not show up? I know I have done this before using Toolbar successfully.

Comment: PEBCAK! I fixed my problem by changing android:actionLayout to app:actionLayout. https://github.com/paulpv/ToolbarSwitch/commit/a002480ecfb6cb42d07b8c754c0469d8be61e9e9#diff-6b571ea58ae7b19ef8d90e469c5004a7

Comment: did not you see that from my answer?

Comment: Yes, but many other examples show "android:actionLayout", and there is no lint warning about that like there is for the "android:showAsAction" attribute. Thanks for the help anyway...but now I have another problem... (working on it...i'll post here)

Comment: New problem posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664412/android-toolbar-actionlayout-of-switch-causes-text-to-jump-when-menu-is-pressed

Comment: You know this answer not just for you, so you have responsibility to confirm it is correct/accept.