# Android Toolbar actionLayout of Switch causes text to jump when menu is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

Please refer to my project at:
https://github.com/paulpv/ToolbarSwitch

I am working on a simple custom layout for the Android Toolbar (aka: new ActionBar).
This simple control adds a Switch to the Toolbar, and can be seen here highlighted in magenta:

[image]

My problem is that immediately when the overflow menu is pressed, the Switch's Text jumps to the top of the Toolbar, and remains that way when you close the overflow menu:

[image] [image]

A similar thing happens in Landscape orientation (the subtle difference being that the overflow menu popup doesn't have any top padding).

[image]

[image]

[image]

What can I do to my menu item's actionLayout to prevent the text from jumping?

menu/menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_switch"
        android:title="@string/action_switch"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar_switch"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

layout/toolbar_switch.xml

```
<Switch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/action_switch"
    android:text="@string/action_switch"
    android:switchPadding="10dp"
    android:background="#ff00ff"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Obviously, I think I could create two Views, one TextView, and one Switch, where I separately set the text on the TextView and I don't directly set the Switch's text...but I would prefer to set the text directly on the Switch.

I have a few other questions:

1. When using an ActionBarActivity and inflating the Toolbar menu, why is onResume called before onCreateOptionsMenu?
2. Conversely, in the same circumstance as #1, why is onCreateOptionsMenu not called between onCreate and onResume?
3. In landscape mode, the title text size is noticeably smaller; is this expected and desirable?
4. What can I do to set the landscape title text size to be the same as the portrait text size?

Thanks!

Pv

Comment: off-topic: Your icon padding is screwed up because you're using `minHeight` on your toolbar. Ditch it and set the `android:layout_height="?actionBarSize` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was following your code to add Switch to my action bar and I was able to solve your problem with the "jumping text" by setting the width of the Switch to wrap_content like this:

```
<Switch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/action_switch"
    android:text="@string/action_switch"
    android:switchPadding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had tried that (and have no idea why I was using the deprecated "fill_parent" when I usually use "match_parent"). I'll give you credit for this even though I haven't tried it out yet.

Comment: Thanks for that! I can assure you it works, I used exactly the same code for my layout. :)

Comment: I have the same issue, looks like the overflow is the reason, since I'm just using two items, on my menu (one with show as action never) any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to use the built in Text field of a Switch or SwitchCompat control.
I ended up providing a layout with a separate TextView field:

layout/toolbar_switch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_switch_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Switch"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/action_switch_control"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```